# Run JQuery first and then download files when link clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link which has direct file download URL in it. So when a user click on the link, that file downloads.

Here is the link:

```
<a class="download-video" href="http://mylink.mp4?file=1&name=A Video"> Download</a>
```

I was hoping to run some JQuery before this file downloads. I was able to work a solution, but instead of direct downloading, I am redirected to the video. All I want is to download withouth any redirection. This is what I tried:

```
$('a.download-video').click(function(event) {

    var href = this.href;
    //My JS Code
    alert(href);

    event.preventDefault();

   window.location = href;
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to add the `download` attribute to the HTML link? http://caniuse.com/#search=download and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the [download attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) to the anchor tag and then just don't use `preventDefault();`

```js
$('a.download-video').click(function(event) {

    var href = this.href;
    //My JS Code
    alert(href);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="download-video" href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4?file=1&name=A Video" download> Download</a>
```

Here's a [link for browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download).